# Basement concrete leveling issue for click lock hardwood flooring installation

Tags: concrete, hardwood-floor, remodeling, preparation, leveling

I am prepping my basement concrete flooring to install [click lock hardwood](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Home-Legend-Matte-Chamois-Mahogany-3-8-in-Thick-x-5-in-Wide-x-Varying-Length-Click-Lock-Hardwood-Flooring-19-686-sq-ft-case-HL303H/205756512). The problem I saw is that there is a spot in the corner with this:

[image]

I am not sure what it is as it looks like a cap to cover something. BUT the problem is that area is a bit higher (like 0.5" difference with the cap).

What should I do to prep the surface for **click lock floating floor installation**?

Do I need to put down any underlayment?

Or should I just ignore this and it will be OK?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you referring to that's 2 inches high? All I see is a plumbing cap that barely extends above the concrete. Is there a mound in the concrete that's not apparent from the angle of the photo?

Comment: It is not 2". Sorry it was a typo. It's probably just 0.5" difference over 5' span I suspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the issue is a bulge in the concrete, I'd be fixing that first. You cannot lay wood flooring over that severe of a bend. Either break up the hump and remove it, or cut out the entire area and refill with concrete.

You'll want to shorten the pipe and install a cleanout plug (threaded fitting). This should be slightly below the surface of the concrete. You can then install a stainless steel cover after the flooring is installed.

Comment: Is it OK to use self leveling concrete? Also, is it possible to get around by using thick underlayment to smooth it out?

Comment: I don't know how you'd use self-leveling cement in this case, and I can't imagine how you'd build up 2" with underlayment. Rent yourself a diamond saw and get to it. :)

Comment: It is not 2". It is about 1/2" (typo earlier).

Comment: Still. You'd rather purchase and lay something over the *entire* floor than make this repair?

Comment: I can make the repair. I am not sure what is below the cap there. What happened if I break the entire drain pipe? And if I remove the hump, what is the ideal tool for this?